# Mailgun, receive mail on root domain and not just subdomain

Tags: dns, mailgun

I created a subdomain for Mailgun, mail.example.com, and added all the DNS settings they told me to add (TXT, CNAME, MX).

After adding the MX records on mail.example.com I added a route in the Mailgun settings which catches mail coming to something@mail.example.com and forwards to my Gmail, and that all works fine.

How would I catch mail coming to something@example.com (the root domain, not the subdomain)?

Do I just add the MX records (mxa.mailgun.org and mxb..) on the root domain also?

Comment: Have you been able to receive email to your root domain?

Answer (score 4):

Within DNS the root of the domain i.e.`example.com` is called the apex, and uses the `@` symbol.

So to set an MX record to the apex of the domain you would set a record something like this

```
@     IN MX   10 mail.example.com
@     IN MX   20 mail2.example.com
etc
```

If you set those records to mail instead of the apex, then you will get mail at something@mail.example.com

```
Mail     IN MX   10 mail.example.com
Mail     IN MX   20 mail2.example.com
```

Comment: The problem is that google apparently doesn't let you add two mx records for the same subdomain. Adding `10 mail.example.com` works but when trying to also add `20 mail2.example.com`, it says "Record already in use".